# using getJSON to display list of customers (name, address) in MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm trying to get list of customers (name and address) when one types the country name in textbox and clicks the button.

Here is the view:

```
<p>
    Enter country name @Html.TextBox("Country")
    <input type="submit" id="GetCustomers" value="Submit"/>
</p>
```

Here is the JSON call:

```
<script type="text/jscript">
    $('#GetCustomers').click(function () {

        //var url = "/Home/CustomerList";
        //var Country = $('#Country').val();
        //$.getJSON(url, { input: Country }, function (data) {

        $.getJSON('/Home/CustomerList/' + $('#Country').val(), function (data) {

            var items = '<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Address</th></tr>';
            $.each(data, function (i, country) {
                items += "<tr><td>" + country.ContactName + "</td><td>" + country.Address + "</td></tr>";
            });
            items += "</table>";

            $('#rData').html(items);
        });
    })
</script>
```

Here is the controller:

```
public JsonResult CustomerList(string Id)
{
    var result = from r in db.Customers
                    where r.Country == Id
                    select r;
    return Json(result);
}
```

***My problems are:***

**i) When I'm using following**

```
var url = "/Home/CustomerList";

var Country = $('#Country').val();

$.getJSON(url, { input: Country }, function (data) {
```

It is not passing prameter to CustomerList method, however following works fine

```
$.getJSON('/Home/CustomerList/' + $('#Country').val(), function (data) {
```

**ii) When I'm using following JSON**

```
$.getJSON('/Home/CustomerList/' + $('#Country').val(), function (data) {
```

and then following CustomerList method

```
public JsonResult CustomerList(string Id)
{
    var result = from r in db.Customers
                    where r.Country == Id
                    select r;
    return Json(result);
}
```

It works fine when I use 'string Id' but when I use 'string country' and then 'where r.Country == country', not works.

**iii) Is this correct way to work with response, not working**

```
var items = '<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Address</th></tr>';
$.each(data, function (i, country) {
    items += "<tr><td>" + country.ContactName + "</td><td>" + country.Address + "</td></tr>";
});
items += "</table>";

$('#rData').html(items);
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try placing `data` there instead of `input` here `$.getJSON(url, { data: Country }, function (data) {`

Comment: i) @Jai nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 $('#GetCustomers').click(function () {

    //var url = "/Home/CustomerList";
    //var Country = $('#Country').val();
    //$.getJSON(url, { input: Country }, function (data) {

    $.getJSON('/Home/CustomerList/' + $('#Country').val(), function (data) {

        var items = '<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Address</th></tr>';
        $.each(data, function (i, country) {
            items += "<tr><td>" + country.ContactName + "</td><td>" + country.Address + "</td></tr>";
        });
        items += "</table>";

        $('#rData').html(items);
    },'json');
});
```

Here is the docs http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/